# Issue regarding resolution of incoming intents by intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Ran into an issue regarding resolution of incoming intents by intent filters & wants to know the exact reason for this behaviour.

I have an activity that has an intent filter as below

```
 <activity android:name=".deeplink.DeeplinkActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="dltest" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

All was working as expected, that is it did resolve URIs of the format **dltest://test1**

Then I had to support URL of the format **https://www.mine.com/**
for which I added a new data tag to same intent filter resulting in

```
  <activity android:name=".deeplink.DeeplinkActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.mine.com"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="dltest" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now it does handle URIs of both types, but it also handle all intents with scheme as https and host as anything (wild card) that is of the unspecified format for eg: **https://developer.android.com**

```
<data
     android:host="*"
     android:scheme="https" />
```

I know that it can be solved by separating two data tags into two different intent filters inside same activity, but I couldn't figure out how the above resolution strategy works from anywhere. Can anyone help me with the reason

Comment: Multiple elements of the same type result in logical OR's of the conditions. So, your two `<category>` elements mean that an `Intent` with `DEFAULT` *or* `BROWSABLE` will match the `Intent`. Your experiments suggest that with `<data>` the logical OR's are by individual attribute. So, an `Intent` with a scheme of `https` *or* `dltest` and a host of `www.mine.com` *or* `*` would match. That's just a guess -- I have not tried this style of multiple `<data>` elements in a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google in one of its official android documentation said that

> Although it's possible to include multiple  elements in the same
>   filter, it's important that you create separate filters when your
>   intention is to declare unique URLs (such as a specific combination of
>   scheme and host), because multiple  elements in the same intent
>   filter are actually merged together to account for all variations of
>   their combined attributes. For example, consider the following:

```
<intent-filter> 
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

It might seem as though this supports only https://www.example.com and app://open.my.app. However, it actually supports those two, plus these: app://www.example.com and https://open.my.app.

So basically as [@commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said it performs kinda logical **OR** behind the scenes ...and thus ensures that all combinations are met

Source : [Create Deep Links to App Content](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Comment: Thanks, I went through https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DataTest

Could not find hints here

Comment: @RameesThattarath Thanks to you also man for such a good question... Happy Coding :)